# Passport validity required to enter UK and Schengen countries for Indians with valid visas

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, indian-citizens

My daughter has valid visas for the United Kingdom and the Schengen area but has passport validity of 4 to 5 months only. Can she still travel to both these countries?

Answer (score 1):

The visas granted could not have been granted beyond the passports validity date. She can definitely travel to these countries before the visa/passport has expired. If the duration of stay is longer than the expiry date, then obviously she will have to renew her passport from your countries embassy/consulate and apply for an extension of her visas/stay permit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the Schengen countries are concerned, she can travel [under the condition](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k6678075-New_Schengen_rule_regarding_passport_validity-Air_Travel.html) that the passport remains valid *for at least three months after she leaves the Schengen area*.
Note also that her passport [should not be more than 10 years old](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/passport-requirements.html) and that [the renewed passports that are more than 10 years old are not allowed](http://www.embassyportugal-us.org/Embassy_of_Portugal/Visa_Info_for_Schengen_States.html).